# Which grant type will be used, if there are a few specified grand types in the client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have an Oauth server. And I use InMemoryClientDetailsServiceBuilder for clients. But even I have a lot of grant types, my oauth client and server always use the authorization_code grand type. Why?

Code example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("myClient1")
                .secret("dsfsdfewrewr324")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
                .authorities("USER", "ADMIN")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .autoApprove(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It depends on the client grant type property.

We can configure it in the application props like this

```
my.client.clientId: myClient1
my.client.clientSecret: dsfsdfewrewr324
my.client.accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8789/server/oauth/access_token
my.client.userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8789/server/oauth/authorize
my.client.grantType=implicit

my.resource.userInfoUri: http://localhost:8789/server/api/me
```

But we could leave the grantType property empty, because some of OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails implementations, like AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails, fill it.

I always got errors because I alwayse used AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails instead of ImplicitResourceDetails for example.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("my.client")
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails client() {
    return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
}
```